# MongoDB on Mint

Tags: linux, mongodb, mongo-shell, linux-mint-21

How to install MongoDB on Linux Mint 21?
I have tried every tutorial available on the internet but it doesn't work can anyone explain step by step?

The following packages have unmet dependencies:   mongodb-org-server: Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable   mongodb-org-mongos: Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
This is the error I am getting

Comment: I was able to install it later. Instead of following the commands for debian 11, follow the commands for Ubuntu 22 (latest) from MongoDB 's official documentation